# How to access my VM guests from other devices in same WiFi network?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a Windows 10 host that has guest VMs running NAT.

The host and other physical devices on the network are on 192.168.0.x subnet
The guest VMs seem to be on 192.168.32.x subnet
The guest VMs can ping everyone (physical devices on the same network, and the guest VMs).
The host can ping everyone (physical devices on the same network, and the guest VMs).
However, the other physical devices on the same network cannot ping the guest VMs.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

In NAT mode your VMs are on a second network and your host acts as a router.  Just like how your other devices cannot be directly accessed from the internet due to your home router, your VMs cannot be directly accessed from your network because they are behind the host pc router.  In order to access them in this mode you need to [setup port forwarding](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_net_nat_advanced.html) in the VM software.

If you want to be able to access the VMs directly and not have to setup forwarding then you need to configure them to use a [bridged network connection](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_bridged_ws.html) instead of NAT.  This puts the VMs on the same network as the host and they will acquire a 192.168.0.x IP just like your other devices on the network.